# Cookie popup while parsing webpage into document (JScript ES3)

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, jscript

I am using the following code to download a webpage and parse it into an HTML file in JScript (ECMAScript 3);

```
var D = new ActiveXObject('htmlfile');
var X = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0'), method = 'GET', url = 'someurl';
X.open(method, url, false); X.send();
D.open();D.write(X.responseText);D.close();
```

While this works fine to get the page, I get "To allow this website to provide information personalized for you, will you allow it to put a small file (called a cookie) on your computer"

Is there a way to automatically suppress/deny this?

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings:

1. Internet Options> Privacy> try a setting of Low or Accept all.
2. Internet Options (General tab). Browsing History> verify that Delete browsing history on exit is not checked.
3. If a third-party security/privacy program is "managing" cookies, you may have to disable that feature.

More information, you could check these articles: [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/how-to-stop-the-following-pop-up-windows-security/b57cf9c2-dddc-4e45-bbd1-ee6c3e471749), [here](https://community.norton.com/en/forums/windows-security-warning-cookies) and [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/17479/windows-internet-explorer-11-change-security-privacy-settings).

Comment: Understood, but I want to know how I can circumvent in jscript rather than having to change windows settings. I don't understand why the pop-up comes when rendering the HTML response into a htmlfile.